# Masking/Unmasking sensitives data using Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a POC of web application that has been developed using java spring boot. In my application, I have sensitives data that and I want to add masking/unmasking feature to protect them. So by default, all sensitives data are partially masked. And if the user click on a button it will retrieve the unmasked value
from server side and log the action. As well for security reason, it's really important to say that both process of masking and unmasking are performed on server side (not on client side).

For example, let's say that we have a phone number inside the web page. By default, the phone number is displayed like this : **(xxx) xxx-x234**
On clicking a button, it retrieve the value from server side and log the action. After that the phone number is displayed like this : **(123) 123-1234**

The big deal for me is on how to store and retrieve data the masked and the clear values of all sensitives data.
After couple days of reflexion, I'm thinking that the better strategy to do this, is to store all sensitives data in session. I'm thinking about using @SessionAttributes or scoped proxy for storing the data.
The following Json is just a way to show you how I will store it.

```
[
    {
        guid: 'unique-random-id',
        masked: '(xxx) xxx-x234'
        unmasked: '(123) 123-1234'
    },
    ...
]
```

The GUID key is just used to retrieve the clear value from the web page; technically, the user click on the button to unmask data and we send the guid as an ajax parameter to get the clear value.

So my question is that, is there any better approaches to make this ? Can you give me some ideas on how I could improve my solution ?

Thank you